# I want to join three tables using LINQ query at present i am hitting DB three times to get the result

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

```cs
var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(request.Email);
var Menuss = await _context.MenuPermissions
      .Where(x => x.UserId == user.Id && x.IsHide==false)
      .Select(x => x.MenuId)
      .ToListAsync();
var getMenus = await _context.Menus
      .Where(x => Menuss.Contains(x.Id))
      .Include(x => x.MenuPermissions)
      .ToListAsync();
```

In the above code I am trying to get the menu permission for the current user

1. First I am fetching current user
2. I have one table by name `menupermission` where I have user id as foreign key to get the permissions
3. Using the `menuid` from the `menupermission` table I am getting the menus for that user

Below is the dto

```cs
public class GetMenuForUserDto
{
      public Guid Id { get; set; }
      public string EngName { get; set; }
      public string Title { get; set; }
      public int Rank { get; set; }
      public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }
      public string RoutePath { get; set; }
      public bool IsHide { get; set; }
      public string Icon { get; set; }
      public string Type { get; set; }
      public GetMenuPermissionsDto MenuPermissions { get; set; }
}

public class GetMenuPermissionsDto
{
      public Guid Id { get; set; }
      public string UserId { get; set; }
      public Guid MenuId { get; set; }
      public bool Add { get; set; }
      public bool Edit { get; set; }
      public bool View { get; set; }
      public bool Delete { get; set; }
      public bool IsHide { get; set; }
}
```

I am using EF6

Comment: Add result DTO definition. It is not clear what should be at the end. Also specify EF version, your question have bad tags.

Comment: Well, still not enough. It is needed `User`, `MenuPermission`, `Menu` entities with navigation properties.

Answer (score 0):

Navigation properties are the key to using EF efficiently. Based on your table structure, assuming MenuPermissions contains more detail than just a MenuId and a UserId, you can opt for something like:

```
public class Menu
{
    [Key]
    public int MenuId { get; protected set; } 
    
    // other menu fields...

    public virtual ICollection<MenuPermission> MenuPermissions { get; protected set; } = new List<MenuPermission>();
}

public class MenuPermission
{
    [Key]
    public int MenuPermissionId { get; protected set; }

    public bool Hide { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MenuId")]
    public virtual Menu Menu { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

plus an entity for User. User doesn't need a collection of MenuPermissions, the relationship can be defined and used one way. Most basic relationships between entities can be resolved by EF automatically provided they follow basic conventions. Worst case you might need to add some configuration via attributes or modelBuilder mapping. I tend to be explicit with configuration. The above use Shadow Properties for the FK fields (recommended) rather than adding things like MenuId and UserId as properties to the MenuPermission. I recommend shadow properties to leave the navigation property as the single source of truth for the relationship.

Now when you want to get Menus for a given user:

```
var menus = await context.Menus
    .Where(m => m.MenuPermissions.Any(mp => mp.User.Email == request.EmailAddress))
    .ToListAsync();
```

This will build a query with the required joins to fetch Menus based on the user Email address through the permissions.

The above entity assumes MenuPermissions has it's own PK. If you use a composite key of MenuId and UserId as the PK then you just need to define this as the PK using the modelBuilder in the DbContext OnModelCreating. (For EF Core. For EF 6 [non-Core] you can set up composite keys with attributes.)

Comment: I do not see any table structure in original question, also answer do not show projection to DTO.